# Git revert doesn't revert file

Tags: git, git-revert, reverting

I have a very strange situation with GIT, first time see this. So basically in version control it shows me that i have one changed file. This file is an svg: **file_test.svg**

When i revert it, it just replaces this file with **File_Test.svg**.
If i try to revert **File_Test.svg**, it replaces it back with **file_test.svg** and so on...

So, how that is possible, i didn't touch this svg file + why i can't revert it. Maybe guys you've seen this problem before, how did you resolve it?

Comment: And you're literally just running "git revert" ya?

Comment: git revert option from WebStorm, also git checkout -- file_test.svg

Comment: You could always try `git reset HEAD` if you're trying to just get back to the previous commit's version.

Comment: This is a local change, i didn't change/touch this file, i didn't commit it to do git reset HEAD

Comment: Do you have this file opened by some other tools or editors?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, no, of course no

Comment: Perhaps the repository has both `File_Test.svg` and `file_test.svg` with different capitalization. Anybody working in linux will see two files, people working in Windows will get very strange behaviour.

Comment: @Mort there is just one file, i've checked this for sure!

Comment: How did you check?

Comment: Besides the "two files with one case" issue, there's also "one file with two different cases", which occurs in the opposite direction, on Windows. The Linux user will experience the different cases consistently, while the Windows user will get whichever case was last successfully created in the work-tree (not random, really, but it kind of *seems* random, though you'll get this alternating behavior a lot).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with my svgs. I have not found a solution other than to commit the changes git thinks it found.

Answer (score 0):

To reset local changes for a specific file you can use the command:

```
git checkout -- pathToFile
```

When you add this file by mistake you need to use

```
git reset HEAD pathToFile
```